# Firebase iOS SDK Realtime Database crash NSInternalInconsistencyException [FTrackedQueryManager setQueryActive:forQuery:]

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

We have an ongoing bug reported in Firebase Crashlytics that we don't know where to look for.

iOS 16-17
Firebase 10.5.0

We're using Firebase Realtime Database with persistency turned on. From the stack trace, it seems the SDK is at some point trying to deactivate a query that wasn't tracked in the first place. Does anyone know in what situation could this inconsistency happen? Is it something wrong on our side or an internal error? Would an update to a newer Firebase version solve it (I went through release notes for the next 15 versions but haven't seen it mentioned anywhere)?

We are not able to easily reproduce it, it only happens in production and we only know about it due to users sending us crash videos and Firebase Crashlytics reports. It's usually also accompanied by a really long loading time (it's a chat, so we're loading user's messages). We're observing data, the messages load and then at some point after it crashes either with no action or user sending a message therefore updating database.

The only mention I found about this on the internet is this being reported in the Android Firebase SDK [Github](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/issues/1940) issues section.

Fatal Exception: NSInternalInconsistencyException
If we're setting the query to inactive, we should already be tracking it!

This is the stack trace.

```
Fatal Exception: NSInternalInconsistencyException
0  CoreFoundation                 0x99288 __exceptionPreprocess
1  libobjc.A.dylib                0x16744 objc_exception_throw
2  Foundation                     0x132340 _userInfoForFileAndLine
3  Lavendr                        0x62b2e8 -[FTrackedQueryManager setQueryActive:forQuery:] + 116 (FTrackedQueryManager.m:116)
4  Lavendr                        0x628f88 -[FPersistenceManager setQueryInactive:] + 168 (FPersistenceManager.m:168)
5  Lavendr                        0x5fd638 __37-[FRepo getData:withCompletionBlock:]_block_invoke.83 + 586 (FRepo.m:586)
6  Lavendr                        0x5f5208 __33-[FPersistentConnection sendGet:]_block_invoke + 787 (FPersistentConnection.m:787)
7  Lavendr                        0x5f3494 -[FPersistentConnection onDataMessage:withMessage:] + 376 (FPersistentConnection.m:376)
8  Lavendr                        0x62d1e4 -[FConnection onDataMessage:] + 169 (FConnection.m:169)
9  Lavendr                        0x62d09c -[FConnection onMessage:withMessage:] + 151 (FConnection.m:151)
10 Lavendr                        0x62e2d4 -[FWebSocketConnection appendFrame:] + 303 (FWebSocketConnection.m:303)
11 Lavendr                        0x62e37c -[FWebSocketConnection handleIncomingFrame:] + 315 (FWebSocketConnection.m:315)
12 Lavendr                        0x64284c __31-[FSRWebSocket _handleMessage:]_block_invoke + 795 (FSRWebSocket.m:795)
13 libdispatch.dylib              0x1e6c _dispatch_call_block_and_release
14 libdispatch.dylib              0x3a30 _dispatch_client_callout
15 libdispatch.dylib              0xb124 _dispatch_lane_serial_drain
16 libdispatch.dylib              0xbc80 _dispatch_lane_invoke
17 libdispatch.dylib              0x16500 _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread
18 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x10bc _pthread_wqthread
19 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0xe5c start_wqthread
```

Thank you anyone for any suggestions where to look.

Comment: "Questions seeking debugging help ('**why isn't this code working?**') must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)" and [Build a minimal, complete, reproducible example](https://overflow.tips/write-good-question/minimal-complete-reproducible-example)

Comment: I'm merely asking on guidance on what the error means. As I already stated above, we cannot reproduce it.